# How to freeze an array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability

In js I can **freeze** an array after adding some elements to an array.
Is there anything to freeze an array in *Swift*?

> What is freezing?
>
> Ans: Suppose we have an array. We add some elements
>   to that array.

```
/* This is javascript code */
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");
// fruits contains some elements

// Now freeze fruits. After freezing, no one can add, delete, modify this array.
Object.freeze(fruits);
```

My question is here - **"Is there anything in swift where we can freeze an array?"**

Comment: `no one can add, delete, modify this array` do you mean this at runtime 
?

Comment: Yes. After this freezing this array becomes immutable at runtime. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an immutable copy of the array, but the mutability of objects is only controlled by the variable declaration (`let` for immutable and `var` for mutable), so once you create a mutable object, you cannot make it immutable or vice-versa.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
fruits.append("Kiwi")

let finalFruits = fruits // Immutable copy
finalFruits.append("Pear") // Gives compile-time error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'finalFruits' is a 'let' constant
```

Comment: Yes, I followed the same way. But is there any technique without copying the array?

Comment: @DávidPásztor, unless it's some custom `Collection` type, which behaves like `Array` only has `freeze()` method that disable all mutable operations